# Citation generator script

Tags: html, scripting, metadata

I'm looking for a script that generates a full citation (Chicago, Harvard etc.) based for the webpage it's on.

The script could be PHP- or JavaScript-based, could be a WordPress plugin etc. - very flexible at the moment.

Does anyone know of one?

Note: I know there are WordPress plugins that generate citations of `[cite]` tags on a page. That's not what I'm looking for.